# Dell H710P, Non-Dell SSDs, and RAID Failures

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, ssd

As long as a non-Dell drive is recognized by the H710P controller, and I'm able to set it up in a RAID, will RAID errors with regard to the non-Dell drives be reported?

I setup a RAID10 (16 x 256GB crucial m4 SSDs) in a R720, and it appears in the OS just fine, but since they aren't OEM drives all the amber lights are always blinking.  I can live with that, but what I can't live with is a non-Dell drive failure within the RAID that isn't reported by the H710P controller, since it isn't Dell branded.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Yes, they would be reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which is the OS and do you have the option to install Server Administrator?, with it you can see the state of the HDs and with another application you can configure it to send you alerts in case of failure, the alert of a failure are going to reported by the controller so I don't see why a possible failure cannot be reported.
But if I'm sincere I never saw a Dell Server with non-Dell SSDs.

I think tomorrow I can have more information about it.

Comment: Hey Coré, these systems will be running OME (current day Server Administrator), and be monitored via iDRAC as well.  It seems RAID failures would be reported, just curious for some feedback, thanks!

Comment: Hi Heyjon, perfect, with server administrator and monitoring via iDRAC you don't need to have too much problems. Just for your info, these are the states of the HD leds: Blinks green, amber, and off Predicted drive failure 
Blinks amber four times per second Drive failed 
Blinks green slowly Drive rebuilding 
Steady green Drive online 
Blinks green three seconds, amber three seconds, and off six seconds Rebuild aborted